# Combinatorics dividing students into one team

Tags: combinatorics

There are 23 athletes, 11 boys, 12 girls. Each one of them has two T-shirts, a blue one and a red one. How many ways to assemble a team of 11 athletes , all girls are in red and all boys are in blue ?

Firstly we choose the team : 23 athletes taken 11

I don't know how exactly should I distribute the persons according to their T-shirts color.

Comment: If the team members have been chosen then the colors of their shirts are determined. So choosing team members is enough here. $\binom{23}{11}$ possibilities.

Comment: I agree with you, but in (23 11) possibilities we also have the girls in blue and the boys in red, isn't it ?

Comment: Any girl in the selection is forced to choose her red shirt.